# Get top-6 elements, subject to the condition that element >= 3

Tags: python, heap, top-n

I'm trying to make a list of 11 elements

I want to pop out the maximum element only from `l[0]` to `l[5]`. under one of the two conditions:

`l[5] >= 3` or `l[5]` is no longer exist or `None`.

```
l = [2,8,6,2,8,7,9,8,6,7,4]
max = 0
maxIndex = 0
while (l[5] >= 3 or l[5] is None):
    for x in range(6):
        if l[x] > max:
            max = l[x]
            maxIndex = x
    l.pop(maxIndex)
print(l)
```

I am getting the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know at some point `l[5]` will no longer exist, but how can I create this code.

Comment: Add a condition in the while statement which should go first. It should be: `len(l) > 5`

Comment: Your function is rather complex; all you really need is [`heapq.nsmallest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) here.

Comment: You want the **top-n (here, n=6), subject to the condition that x >= 3**. As @MartijnPieters said, don't start from a list in the first place, use a self-sorting data structure like `heapq`

Comment: Don't say *"pop... from a list"*. Say *"Get top-n"*. State your problem without nailing it down to specific data structures or operations.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal reproducible code:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l[3] is None # raises IndexError
assert len(l) == 3 # len(l) returns 3
```

As you can see, accessing non-existing item raises an IndexError, so correct condition should contain length test.

```
while (len(l) >= 6 and l[5] >= 3):
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the conditions:

```
l = [2,8,6,2,8,7,9,8,6,7,4]
max = 0
maxIndex = 0
while len(l) > 5 or l[5] >= 3:
    for x in range(6):
        if l[x] > max:
            max = l[x]
            maxIndex = x
    l.pop(maxIndex)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does all you need - returns maximum if there is a 5th element and it's `>=3` or `None`

```
>>> l =  [2,8,6,2,8,7,9,8,6,7,4]

>>> max(l[0:5]) if len(l)>5 and (l[5]>=3 or l[5] is None) else None
8

>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> max(l[0:5]) if len(l)>5 and (l[5]>=3 or l[5] is None) else None
>>>
```